# What do superheroes with laser vision/sight see when using their ability?

Tags: comics, super-hero, powers

Heroes such as Superman and Cyclops can produce lasers from their eyes (typically red). But I'm wondering what exactly do they see when their abilities are active. My guesses are:

1. A black void/complete whiteness (unlikely as they wouldn't be able to aim).
2. They don't actually see the lasers produced, but they feel their effect and can thus easily focus it.
3. A colorful overlay with the laser's color overlaps the entirety of their view.

So far I've not found evidence to support any of these. In fact I can't seem to find any medium where we have a character project beams from their eyes in first person.

EDIT: Just to clarify why this is different than the question exclusively regarding Superman's vision. Superman's ability is officially called "heat vision", and there's an implication that it's not even visible to other people, but is drawn simply to show readers. This is usually how it's depicted in older comics, and the only reason I'm even mentioning Superman in my post is because in modern comics he projects full red lasers, including in the movie, which are definitely visible to the naked eye.

Comment: See also: [How does Cyclops see?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/14470/5184)

Comment: VTC as too broad. the answer is likely to vary between companies and characters.